# conditional update/inserting rows

Tags: join, sql-update, mysql-workbench, sql-insert

i need helping populating a table (job_desired) with data from other tables that meet certain conditions.

what i want to insert into job_desired is (contact_id, title, salary_low)

[contact_id] (foreign key refers to my_contacts) - from a junction table called contact_seeking where their seeking_id IN(4,7) ie. employment or new job (contact_id) is a fk in contact_seeking

[title] - from a table called job_listings WHERE it meets the condition below

[salary_low] - also from job_listings WHERE salary_low > salary from a table job_current(has fk contact_id) if that helps at all

i've tried various select statements and an update with a case but to no avail. 
please help out a noob!

Comment: I understand that contact_seeking is a link table. It has contact_id and which other fields? I understand that you have three tables: job_listings with title and salary_low, my_contacts with contact_id and contact_seeking with contact_id and what else?

Comment: contact_seeking has seeking_id and contact_id only. seeking_id refers to a table seeking.  job_listings doesn't have salary_low but just salary. job_listings isn't linked to any other tables just job_current and job_desired that have foeign keys of contact_id the primary in my_contacts. does this help? thank you for the response

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve in terms of a business outcome? Forget MySQL for the moment. What are the criteria for an individual (a "my_contact") to say a particular job is a "job_desired"? Then: what are the fields that contain those criteria and in which tables do I find them?

Comment: ok, then salary is the only criterion. Again, in which tables do you save salary? It is still unclear. Why don't you post your data model? That would make it a lot easier.

Comment: their current salary is in a column 'salary' in table 'job_current' the salary i want to check against is the 'salary' column in job_listings.
this info must go into the table job_desired. does that help? thank you very much for response. i have a schematic of the tables but it won't let me upload it
oh and there is a second criteria - they must be looking for a job so seeking_id from contact_seeking IN(4,7) the values for seeking 'employment' and 'new job'

Comment: ok, so a "job_desired" is any job from "job_listings" paying a higher "salary" then the "salary" from "job_current" of the respective "my_contact". Got it. But now you know the answer to your question yourself, don't you? :-)

Comment: yes that's it! no... i still don't i can share the code that i tried?

Comment: of course, post it pls.

Comment: INSERT INTO job_desired (contact_id, title, salary_low)

SELECT mc.contact_id, jl.title, jl.salary FROM job_listings jl

WHERE seeking.seeking_id IN(4,7)

AND job_listings.salary > job_current.salary;

-- i don't know how to join my_contacts, job_current, and the
-- link table contact_seeking

Comment: sorry it should be contact_seeking.seeking_id IN(4,7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO job_desired(contact_id, title, salary_low)
SELECT 
   a.id, c.title, b.salary
FROM 
   my_contacts a 
INNER JOIN job_current b ON a.id = b.contact_id
INNER JOIN job_listings c ON b.salary < c.salary
INNER JOIN contact_seeking d ON a.id = d.contact_id;
```

assuming that the id field of "my_contacts" is called "id".

This query should hopefully answer this question: a "job_desired" is any job from "job_listings" paying a higher "salary" then the "salary" from "job_current" of the respective "my_contact".

Just give it a try please. I didn't test this! If it doesn't work just let me know.
"salary_low" contains the existing "salary".
**EDIT:** To determine whether the person is actually looking for a job I have just added an inner join to contact_seeking which seems to hold this information?!

Comment: OMG it worked!! thank you so much! this has been troubling me for two days!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem i had with id 7 is that there is no job_current value to compare to job_listings.
so i used the following code to resovle this.

INSERT INTO job_desired (contact_id, title, salary_low)

SELECT cs.contact_id, jl.title, jl.salary FROM job_listings jl

JOIN contact_seeking cs WHERE cs.seeking_id =7

ORDER BY salary

LIMIT 1;

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to achieve in terms of the business outcome? Same as before ... Maybe you can modify the following: “This query should hopefully answer this question: a "job_desired" is any job from "job_listings" paying a higher "salary" then the "salary" from "job_current" of the respective "my_contact".“